# SQL Retain Work around

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if anyone can help me. A bit ashamed to ask but I guess it has come to this.

Is there a simple way to create the column "Beer_Sales" below. I need to add this column to a table I already have that contains store_id, category and sales

```
Store_id Category Sales Beer_sales
1         Beer     100  1
1         Wine     10   1
1         Spirits  5    1
2         Wine     33   0 
2         Sprits   10   0
3         Wine     30   0
```

Basically, if there is a row for beer sales I need every record for that store to have a flag of 1

I can do this with via a nested query but wondered if there is a simpler way to do this

Thanks

Mike

Comment: sorry sql server v10 (APS)

Comment: Solution will depend on what is more important to you - read performance or update performance. If you care about reads more - write extra code to update all rows of that store when changing beer sales. If you care about updates - subquery with calculated column should be fine.

Comment: I already have the data in another table, I just wondered if I can do select *, "insert code here" as beer sales from data

Comment: I am puzzled - is there any connection between the title of the question and the question itself? On the question itself: 1) What do you mean by "create the column"? It looks like the table already has that column, so no need to create it. 2) How do you identify a "row for beer sales"? 3) Which flag do you mean when you say "have a flag of 1". 4) So say you can already do what you want via a nested query - it would be a great help if you posted the code of that query.

Comment: you need to post the design of each table involved here

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. Answer is below. In SAS I can do this with a retain but was having trouble making the beer_Sales column with SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way using `Max()Over()` window aggregate function

```
Select *,
       BeerSales = max(case when Category = 'Beer' then 1 else 0 end)Over(Partition by Store_id)
From yourtable
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I need